# Поиск людей с самым большим количеством общих предпочтений - SWIProlog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

В пролог-программе заданы отношения `likes(Person, Thing)` (`Person` — человек которому нравится вещь `Thing`). Определить предикат `mostResembling(Person1, Person2)` для нахождения людей с самым большим количеством общих предпочтений.

Использую SWI-Prolog.

Написала вот такой код

```
likes(tom,book).
likes(pam,fish).
likes(ann, apple).
likes(ann, cat).
likes(ann, flower).
likes(bob, apple).
likes(bob, cat).
likes(bob, flower).
likes(pem, apple).
likes(pem, cat).
likes(pem, phone).
:-dynamic likesInfo/2.
changeDB(X,Y) :-
        (retract(likesInfo(X, C));  C = 0),
        C1 is C + 1,
        assertz(likesInfo(X, C1)).        
existBetter(X):-
        likesInfo(X,C), likesInfo(X1,C1), C1 > C.
mostResembling(L):-
        forall(likes(X, Y),  changeDB(X,Y)),
        findall(X, (likesInfo(X,  _), not(existBetter(X))), L),
        retractall(likesInfo(_,_)).
```

Но в данный момент у меня находит список людей просто с самым большим количеством предпочтений. А вот как сравнивать сами преподчтения и выбирать самое большое количество?

Answer (score 0):

> Определить предикат mostResembling(Person1, Person2) для нахождения людей с самым большим количеством общих предпочтений.

```
% Поиск пары персон с наибольшим числом общих предпочтений
most_resembling( Person1, Person2 ) :-
     pair_prefs( L ),
     L = ['$pair_prefs'( Common_Things, Person1, Person2 ) | _ ],
     print( L ).

:- dynamic seen/2.

%
likes( tom, book ).
likes( pam, fish ).
likes( ann, apple ).
likes( ann, cat ).
likes( ann, flower ).
likes( bob, apple ).
likes( bob, cat ).
likes( bob, flower ).
likes( pem, apple ).
likes( pem, cat ).
likes( pem, phone ).

% Поиск всех пар персон с любым количеством общих предпочтений
pair_prefs( Prefs1 ) :-
     persons( Persons ),
     things( Persons, PThings_List ),
              bagof( '$pair_prefs'( Common_Things, Person1, Person2 ) ),
       Things1^Things2^Person1^Person2^(
             person_things( Persons, PThings_List, Person1, Things1 ),
             person_things( Persons, PThings_List, Person2, Things2 ),
             is_valid_pair( Person1, Person2 ),
             record_seen( Person1, Person2 ),
             intersection( Things1, Things2, Common_Things )
        ),
        Prefs
     ),
     isort( Prefs, Prefs1 ). 

pair_prefs( [] ).

%
person_things( Persons, Pref_List, Person, Things ) :-
     member( Person, Persons ),
     member( Things,  Pref_List ),
     likes_things( Person, Things ).

% Все персоны, представленные в likes/2
persons( Persons ) :-
     setof( Person, Person^Thing^likes( Person, Thing ), Persons ).

% Все предпочтения, представленнын в likes/2
% и структурированные в соответствии  c likes_things/2
things( Persons, PThings_List ) :-
     bagof( PThings,
          PThings^Person^(
             member(Person, Persons ),
             likes_things( Person, PThings )
          ),
          PThings_List
     ).

     % То же, что и likes/2, за исключением того, что указан список предпочтений
likes_things( Person, Things ) :-
     setof( Thing, Thing^Person^likes( Person, Thing ), Things ).   

% Пара персон применима если они не одна и та же персона
is_valid_pair( Person1, Person2 ) :-
      dif( Person1, Person2 ),
      \+ is_seen( Person1, Person2 ).

% Запись факта истории поиска: пара P1 и P2 проверены
record_seen( P1, P2 ) :- assertz( seen( P1, P2 ) ).

% Проверка факта истории поиска: проверены ли пара P1 и P2
% при любом порядке переменных
is_seen( P1, P2 ) :- seen( P1, P2 ); seen( P2, P1 ).

%
isort([], []).
isort([H|T], R):- isort(T, W), insert(H, W, R).


%
insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [H|T], [X|L]):- X @> H, insert(H, T, L).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|L]):- X @=< H, insert(X, T, L).

:- initialization( goal ).

%
goal :-
      most_resembling( Person1, Person2 ),
      abolish_seen(),
      writef( '\nPersons: %q, %q\n', [ Person1, Person2 ] ).

    % Результат работы pair_prefs/1  
    %  [
    %   '$pair_prefs'([apple,cat,flower],ann,bob),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([apple,cat],bob,pem),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([apple,cat],ann,pem),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],pem,tom),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],pam,tom),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],pam,pem),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],bob,tom),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],bob,pam),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],ann,tom),
    %   '$pair_prefs'([],ann,pam)
    % ]
    % Persons: ann, bob
```

> Но в данный момент у меня находит список людей просто с самым большим количеством предпочтений. А вот как сравнивать сами предпочтения и выбирать самое большое количество?

В приведённом в ответе коде, предпочтения сравниваются и выбираются при нахождении *общего подмножества* для пар множеств предпочтений / вещей ( things ), используя предикат `intersection/3`, а затем, при сортировке, `isort/2` в `pair_prefs/1`, ( при обращённом *стандартном порядке термов* ).